# Sorting by group

Tags: java, sorting, object

I'm struggling on solving this problem using Java

Here is the desired input and output:

```
Input
1,9
1,12
1,7
3,3
2,4
3,2
2,2
output
1 -> 7,9,12
2 -> 2,4
3 -> 2,3
```

I just can implement and print output like this using `Comparable` and `compareTo`

```
1,7,
1,9,
1,12,
2,2,
2,4,
3,2,
3,3
```

but this is not the answer I want. Can someone help me or give me any suggestion?
this is the code I implemented but this is not the one I want.

Comment: You could use a map of `Integer, List<Integer>` type.

Comment: Use a `TreeMap<Integer, TreeSet<Integer>>` and you only have to add the elements then print the contents of both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> result = new TreeMap<Integer, Set<Integer>>();

public void parseInput(int key, int value) {
    if(result.get(key) == null) { // if you have not encountered the first integer yet, add it to your map.
        result.put(key, new TreeSet<Integer>() {{ add(value); }});
    } else { // otherwise, just add your value to your existing set. The set will take care of duplicates.
        result.get(key).add(value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a Map:

```
Map<Integer, List<Integer>> groups = new TreeMap<Integer, List<Integer>>();
```

for each input line, split it the comma and separate the numbers:

```
String[] parts = inputLine.split(',');
int group = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
int member = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
```

where 'group' is the number before the comma, 'member' is the number after.
Find a Map entry for the group, create if it does not exist:

```
List<Integer> list = groups.get(group);
if (list==null) {
  list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
  groups.put(group, list);
}
```

Add the 'member' number to the group:

```
group.add(member);
```

The output is left as an exercise :)

Comment: I think he wants the sublists sorted too.

Comment: good point. In the output phase, you could use Collections.sort() on the list before iterating though it.

Comment: feel like understand but I don't know how to put your code into mine. sorry. can you revise my code above? plz.

Comment: anyone tell me how to print sub list in map(integer, list)?

Comment: look at my answer - it's literally spelt out!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your strings come in a `String[]` something like this should work:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    final List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (sc.hasNext()) {
        final String next = sc.next();
        if ("print".equals(next)) {
            break;
        }
        list.add(next);
    }
    printGrouped(list);
}

public static void printGrouped(Collection<String> args) {
    final TreeMap<Integer, Set<Integer>> map = new TreeMap<Integer, Set<Integer>>() {
        @Override
        public Set<Integer> get(Object key) {
            Set<Integer> list = super.get(key);
            if (list == null) {
                list = new TreeSet<Integer>();
                put((Integer) key, list);
            }
            return list;
        }
    };
    for (final String string : args) {
        final String[] split = string.split(",");
        final Set<Integer> list = map.get(Integer.parseInt(split[0]));
        list.add(Integer.parseInt(split[1]));
    }
    for (final Entry<Integer, Set<Integer>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        final String valueString = entry.getValue().toString();
        System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " -> " + valueString.substring(1, valueString.length() - 1));
    }
}
```

Input:

```
1,9
1,12
1,7
3,3
2,4
3,2
2,2
print
```

Output:

```
1 -> 7, 9, 12
2 -> 2, 4
3 -> 2, 3
```

Comment: thanks bmoriss but there is no main method and still don't know how to add string array into the code above. sorry, I'm beginner. Please make it completed so that I can run in eclipse.

Comment: Easy as pie! Or at least as Java.